# GLFW3 - console error: "WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format"

Tags: opengl, glfw

I am on windows 7 (64-bit) using 32-bit MSVC 2010.

AFAIK, I have linked all my libraries together properly:
Added in the following to options:

**1. VC++ Directories -> Include Directories**
    added: C:\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\include

**2. VC++ Directories -> Library Directories**
    added: C:\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\lib-msvc100

**3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies**
glfw3.lib
opengl32.lib
user32.lib

I also placed the .dll file from library folder into my system32 folder for default execution.

When I compile the test application:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Upon execution, a message comes up in console stating: "WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format".

When I debug the application the message displays after it executes the line 
        "window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);"

I am unsure how to resolve this issue, any ideas?

EDIT: Tried to include as much detail as I could think of...sorry for the late update

EDIT EDIT: Required manufacturer drivers, not windows automatic windows installed ones (despite windows still apparently installing the dirver for the correct "x1350 and x1500 series" driver.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provide more details before your question can be answered. And by "more details", I mean "any details". Because there aren't any.

Comment: You aren't trying to do something silly like run this in a VM or over remote desktop are you?  Or forgot to install your video drivers?

Comment: This error has to do with opengl support on your video card/driver. So unless it's some onboard gpu with chipsets back from the dino age genpfaults presented issues are likely to cause your problems

Comment: @Bisder - I was using automatically installed windows drivers for my Radeon x1500. I just installed the Radeon Catalyst and seems to fix my issue, thx mate!

Comment: I just started getting this error after an update to Windows 8.1. Going to try updating drivers...

Comment: Windows had installed its own WDDM drivers upon updating to Windows 8.1 Pro. Redownloading the latest drivers from the manufacturer's website (AMD, in my case) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon for graphics drivers provided by Microsoft to either have no support for OpenGL or to have only very outdated or limited support. They are above all interested in having the desktop work correctly, which today also means getting Direct3D up and running but certainly not OpenGL.